# How to check whether given input text contains special characters or not using XSL tags

Tags: xslt-3.0

How to check whether given input string contains special characters or not

Input : A'ACHARYA NG'ANGA MAURY'A

Contains special characters

OUTPUT : A'acharya Ng'anga Maury'a

Comment: 1. Define "special characters".   2.  Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your question as xslt-2.0, so I'll mention the regex function `matches()`, which you can use to test whether a string matches a regular expression. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches

Input:

```xml
<test>Aacharya Ng%anga Maury&amp;a</test>
```

XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  
  <!-- define a regex to match "special" characters -->
  <xsl:variable name="specials-regex">[%&amp;]</xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:template match="/test">
    <xsl:value-of select="matches(., $specials-regex)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
true
```

The regular expression language would allow you to define "special" in any way you want, either by listing the characters individually (as I did, above) and/or using the "character classes" defined here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#charcter-classes, e.g `\p{S}` meaning "Symbols", or `\P{L}` meaning "anything except letters".